# jqgrid changing defaults

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Can I remove the verticl scrollbar on jqgrid, as I want to display all the rows without scrolling down.  Am using:

```
$("#grid").jqGrid({

 colModel:...
 shrinkToFit: false,
 height:auto
})
```

The problem I have is whenever I have one or two rows, the grid gets too small, and gets difficult to scroll properly. I need horizontal scrollbar though

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) `$.jgrid.search.caption = "My Search title";` do it.
b) I don't understand your question, so I am unable to answer it.
c) You can find the answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305223/selected-row-background-color/4309531#4309531).

**UPDATED**: You wrote new question instead of the old one. So the answer on the new question:

- you shoud use `height:"100%"` or `height:"auto"` and not `height:auto`, which is wrong
- jqGrid has currently a bug in calculation of the grid width in case of `shrinkToFit: false`. It follows that scroll bars always exist. I suggested the workaround (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/wrong-calculation-of-the-width-of-the-grid-if-shrinktofit-is-false/#p21257)). I hope, that Tony (the developer of jqGrid) will fix the bug in the next jqGrid release. So you has some options now 1) wait for the fix 2) use developer (uncompressed) version of jqGrid and make the described fix (one line only) yourself 3) set grid width explicitly, so that scroll bar will not exist.

If all this will help you not you should post **full** code of the jqGrid with the corresponding test data (it is no problem with two rows of data), so that other people could reproduce your problem.

Comment: Thanks for answering me. But I edited my question with one more issue. Is removing vertical scrollbar possible

Comment: Thanks For replying. I made the change to grid.base.js, and included it in my file. But I keep getting the following error:

Message: Exception thrown and not caught
Line: 580. I get that error even after I removed the change. Should I include any other files with grid.base.js?

Comment: @user508518: Look at the demo http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/WidthBugFixed.htm and include additionally other uncompressed files which you need (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:how_to_install#development_installation).

Comment: Thanks. I was using custom.js instead of common.js.